# Lavaan growth model: to treat endogenous variable as ordinal or continuous

Tags: ordinal-data, structural-equation-modeling, assumptions, lavaan, growth-model

I am modelling the trajectories of scores on two cognitive tests (i.e., PAL and SOS) measured at four time points. To do this I am creating separate latent growth curve models for each cognitive test, using the growth function from lavaan.

However, I am unsure whether I should treat the cognitive variables as ordinal or continuous - note they are endogenous variables within the models. I have a number of covariates as well, which are made up of both continuous, ordinal and dichotomous variables.

I am aware that it is possible to specify that variables are ordinal using the "ordered" argument.

The range of possible scores on both cognitive tests is integers 0-16 for PAL and integers 0-20 for SOS. Despite this, most scores make up only a narrow range of possible scores. The data does not appear to be normally distributed when looking at histograms (see below).

**Should these variables be treated as continuous or ordinal? Are more checks needed?**

Thank you in advance!

**PAL:**
[image: PAL histograms, skewed, kurtotic]

**SOS:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd treat this as continuous.

Treating data as ordinal where there are a large number of categories can lead to computation / identification problems.

Comment: To address non-normality you could use maximum likelihood estimation with robust standard errors and test statistics (e.g., Satorra-Bentler correction).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have incomplete data and will be completing my analysis using lavaan - will the "MLR" estimator option (i.e., Huber-White correction) be appropriate? And can this be used with FIML for missing data? For example, growth(model_PAL.noGrowth.FIML , data=data_wide, missing="fiml.x", estimator = "MLR")

Comment: I have just found this previous answer which addresses my questions in the above comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570637/path-analysis-with-missing-data-and-dichotomous-exogenous-variables-in-lavaan

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianGeiser, would the use of a robust estimator also help overcome issues resulting from outliers? 

In the dataset I'm working with, all scores on the cognitive tests are plausible, however, there are only very few that obtain scores at the extremes (e.g., 1 person out of 7000 scored 16/16 on PAL at baseline, most people score 4 or 5 per image in the original question above).

Comment: If it's only 1 in 7000 that outlier won't make much difference anyway.